# React component not rendering on route changed

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I am trying to render a parent component sub components with a default render component via same route.

For example

A ParentComponent can be access via this route '/dash/overview' 
Now inside the ParentComponent i want to render a default component that has the same route as the ParentComponent.

ParentComponent.js

```
                <Switch>
                  <Route path="/dash/overview/" render={() => <SubComponentOne/>}/>
                  <Route path="/dash/subtwo" render={() => <SubComponentTwo/>}/>
                </Switch>
```

I want to render the `SubComponentOne`.. it's working fine but when i change route to `/dash/subtwo` it doesn't render the `SubComponentTwo`

I am using router `Link` to switch between routes and i am also using `HashRouter`

Comment: Are there any errors in console ?

Comment: There is no errors in the browser console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have `exact` keyword for the `SubComponentOne` Route

```
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/dash/overview/" render={() => <SubComponentOne/>}/>
              <Route path="/dash/subtwo" render={() => <SubComponentTwo/>}/>
            </Switch>
```